# Hide params in Url (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, url

I'm using params to enable tracking of which people I send my URL to actually visit the site (similar to Google campaigns)... it works but looks a bit ugly when they see the page address as mysite.com?ref=abc.

Is there an easy way to simply hide the params on the URL when visiting Wordpress pages - not sure if this is anything to do with WP specifically but mentioned in case it's relevant.

Answer (score -1):

Would it work if instead of saying:

Visit my site: http://www.mysite.com?ref=123

you created an actual link?:

[Visit my site](http://www.mysite.com?ref=123)

I think that would be an easy solution (would require you to send your email as HTML, of course).

Comment: no. It's specifically in the browser navigation bar I want to neaten the URL... e.g they click on http://www.mysite.com/page4?ref=123 and are taken to http://www.mysite.com/page4

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/

Comment: This answer refers to nothing mentioned in the original question (You talk about HTML emails)